# Bad operand types for binary operator ‘&’ First type: int[] Second type: int

Tags: java

```
public static void enterText(String plaintext ) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Plaintext: ");
    plaintext = in.nextLine(); 
    int plaintextLenght = plaintext.length();

    int[] array1 = new int[plaintextLenght]; 
    int[] array2 = new int[plaintextLenght]; 

    StringBuilder quoBinary = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder remBinary = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < plaintext.length() ; i++) {   
        char character = plaintext.charAt(i); 
        int ascii = (int) character; 
        array1[i]= ascii / 10; 
        array2[i] = ascii % 10; 

        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {  
            **quoBinary.append((array1 & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);  
            array1<<= 1;  
            remBinary.append((array2 & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);  
            array2<<= 1;**  
        } 
    }

     System.out.println("Quotient = "+ Arrays.toString(array1));  // Print array for quotients
     System.out.println("Remainder = "+ Arrays.toString(array2)); // Print array for quotients
     System.out.println("Binary QQ " + quoBinary);
     System.out.println("Binary RR " + remBinary);    
}
```

Error message:

```
Bad operand types for binary operator  ‘&’
First type: int[]
Second type: int
```

i couldnot bitwise and an array with int.

Comment: Why would you be able to use bitwise operators on an array? Maybe explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the elements in the array into 8 bit binary

Comment: You also can use left shift `<<` on an array.  You seem to be treating arrays as bit sets.  That doesn't work.

Comment: You look like you're trying to print the ascii values, not "convert the elements into binary."

Comment: Looks to me like those 'array1/array2' mentions are intended to be indexed by ```i```, seeing as how they're inside the for-loop.

Comment: @markspace if you can improve my code, just help by write one, to ease my stress.

Comment: What is intended by this statement, ` array1<<= 1;  `Do you intend to do something on the entire array or on some element of the array? Your question is unclear what it is asking. Is the last statement of your question a summary of your question, "i couldnot bitwise and an array with int." Are you just asking why you cannot perform bitwise operations on an array?

Comment: Is this closer to what you intend to do in your for loops? `            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {  
                quoBinary.append((array1[i] & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);  
                array1[i]<<= 1;  
                remBinary.append((array2[i] & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);  
                array2[i]<<= 1;
            } ` This will compile and if it is close to what you want it will perhaps help us answer you question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert to ascii then.
iterate through the string

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++){
    char character = str.charAt(i);
    System.out.print((int)character);
}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear that this is the answer to what is being asked. The op is already pulling characters out of the string, ` char character = plaintext.charAt(i); ` so I don't see how this answer helps.